# How do I add a column with the same value for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union

I was asked to do a search against our database and to explain the number of clients in the 5 different age ranges. I know I can run the same query five times.  However, i was hoping to be able to create one query that would do the whole job.

To my knowledge, I need to do 5 queries and then use "UNION" to connect the different queries.

The issue is that for each query i want to add a column that says "age range" and then put some text to name the group.

The SQL I came up with was:

```
SELECT     COUNT(CLIENT_ID) AS Client_Count, "0 to 19" AS [Age Group]
FROM         dbo.CLIENTS
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 19)
```

While I hoped this would work, it expects the 0 to 19 to be a column.  How would I let it know that I'm just trying to pass it a fixed value?

Once I get this to work, they would then like that I the values as a percentage of the total.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Try single quotes.

SQL uses single quotes to denote string text. Seems like it would be able to interpret double quotes, but there you have it.

Answer (score 5):

The following should give you a good starting point I think:

```
;with AgeRanges(Low, High) as (
    select 0, 19
    union select 20, 39
    union select 40, 59
    union select 60, 79
    union select 80, 1000
)

select
    count(CLIENT_ID) as Client_Count,
    convert(varchar, Low) + ' to ' + convert(varchar, High) as [Age Group]
from
    dbo.CLIENTS
    inner join AgeRanges
        on  DATEDIFF(year, DOB, getdate()) BETWEEN Low and High
```

Comment: well, nevermind, the above query would give you the ability to do it all at once anyway. either way, good luck :)

Comment: I'd suggest this too: why query 5 times?

Comment: This one is better because it lets you run the full thing as one query.

Comment: Absent the knowledge shown above, 5 queries seemed like my best idea!

Comment: Will this above work in a general "query executor." I'm using visual studio and a pure cut and paste did not work.  I might have to research some of this b/c it might be over my head at the moment.

Comment: What version are you using? It will work in SQL 2005+. If you're in 2000, I can change it around to work.

Comment: I actually just edited it to add 1 more character since, if you're running this as part of a batch of statements, you'll need to put a semi-colon at the beginning of the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Change your speach marks. E.g:

```
SELECT '0 to 19' AS [Age Group]
```

In Full:

```
SELECT     COUNT(CLIENT_ID) AS Client_Count, '0 to 19' AS [Age Group]
FROM         dbo.CLIENTS
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got it right, but if you want the results in columns, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  [0 to 19]  = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN  0 AND 19 THEN 1 END),
  [20 to 39] = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 39 THEN 1 END),
  …
FROM dbo.Clients
```

Comment: I will have to try this. This way of writing SQL is TOTALLY new to me!

Comment: @Scott: I can see now that Jonathan Wood, it seems, has nailed down the actual cause of the problem. Therefore I would like you to realise that the above solution returns the results very differently from your original query. I think now, it was a wrong guess of mine. Of course, if you think it is helpful in your mastering the language, I'm fine with leaving the answer here.

Comment: Give me a sec, I will try it and see what it returns.  Thank you sooooo much for taking the time to respond!

Comment: This turned out awesome! It shows it all as one row rather than 5 rows which is what I initially envisioned.  After executing it, my editor does rewrite the code so that it does not have the "[...] = Count()"

Comment: @Scott: Ah, yes, that is a little peculiarity of mine, to prefer aliasing columns like `alias = expression` to the more standard `expression AS alias`. The two methods are absolutely equivalent in SQL Server.

Comment: Got it. I think I will stick with "AS" b/c SQL SERVER rewrites it to use "AS" and I'm used to it anyway.  I really am not familiar with the "THEN 1 END" is this something that you do regularly?

Comment: @Scott: `COUNT` counts values (as opposed to NULLs), and it doesn't signify what values as long as they are not NULLs. The purpose of `CASE` is to provide `COUNT`s with values under certain conditions only. That is, WHEN the condition is true THEN return a value ('count this') ELSE return NULL ('do not count this'). The ELSE parts are omitted everywhere in my CASE expressions, which means `ELSE NULL` are implied. Finally, as for the actual value, well, `1` is pretty short, isn't it? :) I could use `CLIENT_ID` there like you did in your query, the result would be the same. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Scott: So, in the end, yes, `… THEN 1 END` is something that I do quite often in such cases.